# IntelliJ "Reverse Lookup" of Colors & Fonts?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an html file with some Thymeleaf templating and am having trouble finding where the colors are set in preferences for the template expressions. I've looked in General, Language Defaults, HTML and other places under Colors & Fonts, but no luck.

In this line with my setup, the whitepace between ${ and } has an annoyingly different background color:

```
<div th:if="${someVar != null and someVar == anotherVar}">
```

It would be great if there were some kind of reverse lookup to highlight a section of a file and jump right to the formatting that is controlling it.

Failing that, I'd appreciate any other ideas on where to find the right setting!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on IntelliJ 2017.1 EAP, invoke `Find Action...` <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and search for `Jump to Colors and Fonts` (something short e.g. "jcf" works too). Invoke it to jump to the Colors and Fonts setting corresponding to the element the cursor is on.

However I suspect you want to modify `File | Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General | Injected language fragment`. And this is one that is unfortunately not retrieved by the action mentioned above.

Comment: Alas, this scenario has long since vanished, and I never fully explored the dimensions of your helpful and appreciated comment. However: Thank you for your time and consideration!

Comment: On this site appreciation is usually shown with a vote 